# Run php action for every element

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I have a php script which retrieves data from mysql db.
Everything works fine, but my problem is that this `$result = $dao->joinedEvents($userId);` returns an array of numbers and what I would like to do is to run this `$secondResult = $dao->joinedEventsInfo($receivedIds);` for every ID and this script I'm using right now returns data only for one ID.

This is part of my php script:

```
$userId = htmlentities($_REQUEST["userId"]);

$result = $dao->joinedEvents($userId); //This is getting the IDs array

if(!empty($result)) {


$receivedIds = $result["event_id"];
$ids = explode(",", $receivedIds);

foreach($ids as $id){
    $secondResult = $dao->joinedEventsInfo($id);
    if(!empty($secondResult)) {   
        $returnValue["finalResult"][] = $secondResult;    
    } else {    
        $returnValue["status"] = "error";   
        $returnValue["message"][] = "Could not find records for id" . $id;
    }
}


} else {
    $returnValue["status"] = "Empty error"; 
    $returnValue["message"] = "Could not find records";
}


$dao->closeConnection();
echo json_encode($returnValue);
```

And this is joinedEvents script:

```
public function joinedEvents($userId){

     $returnValue = array();

    $sql = "SELECT event_id from MyTable WHERE userId= '$userId' LIMIT 0 , 30";
      $statement = $this->conn->prepare($sql);
        if (!$statement)
            throw new Exception($statement->error);

        $statement->execute();

        $result = $statement->get_result();

         while ($myrow = $result->fetch_assoc()) 
         {
           $returnValue[] = $myrow;
         }

         return $returnValue;
    }
```

This is joinedEventsInfo script:

```
public function joinedEventsInfo($eventId){

     $returnValue = array();

     $sql = "SELECT * FROM Events WHERE eventId = '$eventId' LIMIT 0 , 30";

    $statement = $this->conn->prepare($sql);
    if (!$statement)
        throw new Exception($statement->error);

    $statement->execute();

    $result = $statement->get_result();

     while ($myrow = $result->fetch_assoc()) 
     {
       $returnValue[] = $myrow;
     }

     return $returnValue;

 }
```

**Edit**: Tha reason I need this is that I have two tables. In the first one I have just IDs and in the second one I have info. So first I need to get the IDs and then I need to get data for every ID I have just received.

Thank you very much , I'm totally stuck.

Comment: In what format this `$receivedIds` is in? Do `var_dump($receivedIds);` and tell us what's it showing.

Comment: I am sorry , butI am not on pc right now but I think that it returns just an array like this : "1,2,3,6"

Comment: *hmm*. Based on your comment and my fair assumption, I've posted an answer below. Hopefully this will resolve your issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the updated code snippets and the discussion below, it is found that `$result` is indeed an array, and **the solution** is:

```
$userId = htmlentities($_REQUEST["userId"]);
$result = $dao->joinedEvents($userId);

if(count($result)){
    foreach($result as $array){
        $event_id = $array['event_id'];
        $secondResult = $dao->joinedEventsInfo($event_id);
        if(!empty($secondResult)) {  
            $returnValue["finalResult"][] = $secondResult;    
        } else {    
            $returnValue["status"] = "error";  
            $returnValue["message"][] = "Could not find records for id: " . $event_id;
        }
    }
}else {
    $returnValue["status"] = "Empty error";
    $returnValue["message"] = "Could not find records";
}
$dao->closeConnection();
echo json_encode($returnValue);
```

Comment: I'm sorry but it returns 1,2,3,4 without ""

Comment: @0ndre_ Yup, that's a string. Test your application with the above code snippet, I believe this will resolve your issue.

Comment: Thanks :) I will do that asap.

Comment: So : {"event_id":2},{"event_id":3} this is what it actually returns.. :/. I am really sorry.

Comment: @0ndre_ Does `echo json_encode($returnValue);` produce this output? What's your expected output?

Comment: @0ndre_ I've updated my answer. Test your application with the updated code snippet, see if you're getting expected output or not.

Comment: I added 2 lines. First one is echo json_encode($result); it prints: [{"event_id":2},{"event_id":3}]  and the second one: echo json_encode($receivedIds); it prints : null . I guess that is the problem :/

Comment: @0ndre_ `echo json_encode($receivedIds);` will print `null` because `$receivedIds` is a string, not an array. Have you tested your application with the updated code snippet, [http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/39560338/2](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/39560338/2)?

Comment: I have updated code what it looks like now. unfortunately it still prints: {"status":"error","message":["Could not find records for id"]}

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123656/discussion-between-rajdeep-paul-and-0ndre).

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried [array_map()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php)?
That would allow you to call a php function on each member of an array easily.

Another way would be to use the common `while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))` which would execute the code in the while loop for each row of your returned results. Note, you will likely have to change the `mysql_fetch_array` to something specific for your SQL connection.

Comment: Please don't assume that OP is using deprecated and dangerous `mysql_*` functions. **Always ask**, that's what comments are for.

Comment: I used those in my example, because I was pretty sure he wasn't using them, but I appreciate your feedback.